# How to update a sheet (probably a cell) in workbook using SharePoint excel Services REST API

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am writing a script to read and update content in an excel file placed in a SharePoint document directory.
I am referring this doc (Sharepoint Excel Services REST API) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/excel-services-rest-api

I can pull different ranges of data from my sheet, but I couldn't find any REST APIs for updating the content in the sheet. 
I know it can achieve using Microsoft Graph API, but I would like to do it using SharePoint Excel Rest API if possible.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you posted it would seem that you may use this kind of request to set a value of an cell and return it

```
http://<ServerName>/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Docs/Documents/sampleWorkbook.xlsx/model/Ranges('Sheet1!A1|G5')?Ranges('Sheet1!C3')=demo
```

Did you try this approach?

I think after you get a range of one cell you should use '=' to set it's value.. like

```
?Ranges('Sheet1!A1')=5.5
```

Comment: I already tried this. It will only reflect in the output, not in the actual document. I want to change the actual excel file.